What are the dimensions of the Canon BG-E6 Battery Grip
What are the dimensions of the Canon BG-E6 Battery Grip for the Canon 5D Mark II?
I would like the height excluding the part that inserts into the camera.
I looked online (I don't have it) but couldn't find anything, does anyone know (or where to search for)?

It adds 41mm (1.63") to the height of the camera.
